# Is there a way to prevent python app from closing when an error occurs?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Disclaimer: I'm very noob with Python, this might be a stupid question or a really serious one. I don't know what to expect.

I edited a trading bot with python, everything works great, but sometimes, probably because of poor internet connections I get an error and the python app closes itself.

The error is this (I'm going to *** sensible data)

```
File "runeth.py", line 217, in <module>
    p = s.my_position(symbol=configeth.SYMBOL)['result']
  File "/home/mosf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybit/__init__.py", line 786, in my_position
    return self._submit_request(
  File "/home/mosf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybit/__init__.py", line 1368, in _submit_request
    raise FailedRequestError(
pybit.exceptions.FailedRequestError: Bad request. retries exceeded maximum. (ErrCode: 400) (ErrTime: 17:29:57).
Request → GET https://api.bybit.com/v2/private/position/list: {'api_key': '*******', 'recv_window': 5000, 'sign': '************', 'symbol': 'ETHUSD', 'timestamp': 1620408574678}.
```

So, after I get this error (too many requests to the exchange API (I guess)) the app closes itself.

**Is there a simple way to prevent this and just tell the app to "try again later" without closing the app?**

I can post the "bot" python code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase maximum [number of retries and the delay between them](https://github.com/verata-veritatis/pybit/blob/master/pybit/__init__.py#L100):

```
session = HTTP(
    endpoint='...', 
    api_key='...',
    api_secret='...',
    max_retries=10,
    retry_delay=15,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept behind implementing a retry with `try/except` is to have a loop that breaks when the operation is successful:

```
while True:
   try:
       result = submit_request()
       break
   except RequestFailedError:
       sleep(1)

# do stuff with result
```

In real life you'd probably put a limit on the number of times to retry instead of doing it forever `while True`, and you might vary the length of the delay, possibly depending on the nature of the failure.